# Spring MVC ajax DELETE method 404 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, spring-form

Help me please with understanding. All done is well, but one method isn't work and I have a 404 error
I have a few requests

```
function deleteFunc(id) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "DELETE",
                url: "/BookList.vw/" + id,
                async: true,
                success: function (response) {
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Book doesn't found");
                }
            });
        }

        function modifyFunc(id) {
            alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/EditBook.vw",
                data: id,
                success: function (response) {
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert('Server problems. You cannot modify this book.');
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/BookList.vw")
public class BookListController {

    @Autowired
    private IBookService bookService;

    public String getModelName() {
        return "BookList";
    }

    public BookListController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView openMain(Model m) throws Exception {
        m.addAttribute("book", new Book());

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<Book> books = bookService.listBooks();
        model.put("books", books);

        return new ModelAndView(getModelName(), "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{id}")
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable int id) throws Exception {
        bookService.removeBook(id);
        return new ModelAndView(getModelName());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView search(@ModelAttribute Book b) throws Exception {
        List<Book> books = bookService.searchBook(b.getName().trim());
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("books", books);

        return new ModelAndView("BookList", "model", model);
    }
}
```

Search and main method work is good, but I can't understand why I have a Error in DELETE method like this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/BookList.vw/2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/BookList.vw/2"
```

i think this url is not correct it may be like this :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/{ApplicationRoot}/BookList.vw/2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you.I used Spring Boot with Spring Security.By defualt , Spring Security will enable the CSRF Protection, all requests using PATCH, POST, PUT, and/or DELETE will be under protection. So ,the simple way is diseable the  CSRF Protection, like:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
        http.csrf().disable();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

on the other way, if you want keep CSRF Protection, you should sumbit the CSRF Token is every request.
If you are using JSON, then it is not possible to submit the CSRF token within an HTTP parameter. Instead you can submit the token within a HTTP header. A typical pattern would be to include the CSRF token within your meta tags. An example with a JSP is shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

You can then include the token within all your Ajax requests. If you were using jQuery, this could be done with the following:

```
$(function () {
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
});
```